# How to write most efficient algorithm to find all possible permutation in list of strings

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, dynamic-programming, python-itertools

The code below outputs number of all possible permutation in list of strings within a constant length solving with recursion. Assume `list_1 = ["A"]` and `list_2 = ["BB"]` an length is `5` then:

All possible combinations are:

```
A A A A A
A A A BB
A A BB A
A BB A A
BB A A A
A BB BB
BB A BB
BB BB A
```

Now, if I change the lists to `list_1 = ["A"], list_2 = ["BB"], list_3 = ["CCCC"], list_4 = ["DDDDDDDD"]`
and length to 256. It takes too much time to respond. I am wondering how can I speed up the code.

```
list_1 = ["A"]
list_2 = ["BB"]
list_3 = ["CCCC"]
list_4 = ["DDDDDDDD"]
size = 256

strs = list_1 + list_2 + list_3 + list_4
res = []

def helper(strs, size, cur, res):
    if size == 0:
        res.append(cur)
        return
    if size < 0:
        return

    for s in strs:
        helper(strs, size-len(s), cur+[s], res)

helper(strs, size, [], res)
print(len(res))
```

Comment: Of course it'll take too long to respond, there are simply way too many permutations.

Comment: What Aplet123 said. Even if you only included list_1 and list_2, and reduced the possibilities further by changing list_1 to "AA", there would be slightly more than 300000000000000000000000000000000000000 permutations to calculate here. Not gonna happen.

Comment: why do you need to use a list to hold the variable if all they have is one string only?

Comment: You mean by defining every list  as a string will improve the code dramatically?

Comment: I'd argue that the most efficient permutations finding algo is just to use the built-in `permuations` from `itertools` module. Don't reinvent the wheel if you can just use one.

Comment: @BurningAlcohol Not sure that does quite what OP is after. This isn't a straightforward permutation because repeats are allowed and not all the options are the same length, so the number of units to arrange isn't fixed.

Comment: Suppose `list_1 = ["A"]` and `list_2 = ["AA"]`. Are `A A` and `AA` considered different permutations?

Comment: NO, they are same.

Comment: You'll need to add that information to the question as it changes the answer.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like your code will give an incorrect result for cases where there's more than one way to form the same string of length `size`. For example, if you set `list_1 = list_2 = list_3 = list_4 = ["A"]` then the answer should always be 1 (because the only possible permutation is a repeating string of "A"s). But your code will instead return an answer of `4^size`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really only interested in the *number* of permutations, you can use memoization (dynamic programming):

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def num_permutations_of_length(l, k):
    if k < 0:
        return 0
    elif k == 0:
        return 1
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        total += num_permutations_of_length(l, k-l[i])

    return total


def main():
    print(num_permutations_of_length((1,2,4,8), 256))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just input a tuple of the lengths of your strings instead of the strings themselves.

This outputs

```
1038196252619804983509071079561190746560608760522777019070489047
```

instantly by the way.

Comment: The answer should be 867355878

Comment: your code outputs right answer for length 16 and 32 and then outputs wrong for 64, 128 and more.

Comment: @Bob Sounds like there is an error in your calculation - 867355878 is waaay too small for the example in your question.

Comment: @ Geoffrey Brent. It's not my calculation. That is answer of test.

Comment: Per clarification from OP on the question, two solutions that result in the same final string but assembled from different pieces are considered identical. This being the case, string length alone isn't enough information for the general case, because the solution for ("A","AA") will be different to the solution for ("A","BB").

Comment: @Bob then either the test answer is wrong, or there's some missing information here. Even if we only count the permutations that are made up from combinations of "AA" (i.e. "A" paired) and "BB", we would find 2^(256/2) = 2^128 = 3.4e38 solutions.